# DocumentDB REST API - Authorization Token Error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

**Problem**

We are seeing this error returned from the DocumentDB REST API whenever we request a list or query, but not when we fetch objects by name/id:

> The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used.

**Background**

We have been successfully using the node.js sdk with DocumentDB for over a year now, but as we want to migrate our back-end restful API code from a node.js App Service to Azure Functions we are seeing 10-30 second lag times come into play as the DocumentDB sdk loads slowly when the Function hasn't been called in a while.  We know that the Function instance is hot, and this isn't a cold instance issue based on previous communication with the Azure Functions team.

To work around this we want to test the DocumentDB REST API which requires zero external libraries to run in a node.js Function and should execute as quickly as possible.

**Code**

This is the test harness running in local node.js.  We'll move this to an Azure Function once it's working.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var crypto = require("crypto"); 
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  var key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var uri = "https://xxxxxx.documents.azure.com";

  var verb = 'GET';
  var type = 'dbs';
  var link = 'dbs';
  var url = `${uri}/${link}`;

  var headers = getDefaultRequestHeaders();

  // var body = `{"query":"SELECT * FROM c", "parameters": []}`;
  var body = '';

  headers['content-length'] = body.length;
  headers['authorization'] = getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, type, link, headers['x-ms-date'], key);

  request[verb.toLowerCase()]({"url": url, "headers": headers, "body": body}, function (error, response, body) {

    // console.log(`error is ${error}`);
    // console.log(`response is ${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`);
    console.log(`body is ${body}`);

    res.status(response.statusCode).json(body);

  });

});

function getDefaultRequestHeaders(isQuery, date) {

  var headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json", 
    "x-ms-date": new Date().toUTCString(),
    "x-ms-version": "2017-02-22",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "user-agent": "xxxxxx/1.0"
  };

  if(isQuery) {
    headers["x-ms-documentdb-isquery"] = true;
    headers["content-type"] = "application/query+json";
  }

  if(date) {
    headers["x-ms-date"] = date;
  }

  return headers;

}

function getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, resourceType, resourceLink, date, masterKey) {  
    var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");  

    var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
               (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
               (resourceLink || "") + "\n" +   
               date.toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
               "" + "\n";  

    var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");  
    var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");  

    var MasterToken = "master";  

    var TokenVersion = "1.0";  

    return encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);  
}  


module.exports = router;
```

We are using the **getAuthorizationTokenFromMasterKey** function verbatim from the [Access control in the DocumentDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources) page.

The key, app name, and user-agent have been replaced with x's for privacy/security.

**Test Results**

*List Databases*

When I try the most basic call to [list dbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/list-databases) the server returns the token error:

```
  var verb = 'GET';
  var type = 'dbs';
  var link = 'dbs';
```

Response:

> "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\ndbs\n\nsat, 12 aug 2017 12:28:41 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: acbf19d9-6485-45c5-9c30-6aa21f14d5b3\"}"

*Get Database*

However, when I perform the [get database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-a-database) request it works fine:

```
  var verb = 'GET';
  var type = 'dbs';
  var link = 'dbs/00001';
```

Response:

> "{\"id\":\"00001\",\"_rid\":\"0eUiAA==\",\"_ts\":1441256154,\"_self\":\"dbs\/0eUiAA==\/\",\"_etag\":\"\\"00007d4a-0000-0000-0000-55e7d2da0000\\"\",\"_colls\":\"colls\/\",\"_users\":\"users\/\"}"

*List Collections*

Similarly, requesting the [list of collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/list-collections) from this database returns a token error:

```
var verb = 'GET';
var type = 'colls';
var link = 'dbs/00001/colls';
```

Respose:

> "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\ncolls\ndbs/00001\nsat, 12 aug 2017 12:32:19 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 8a9d4ff8-24ef-4fd2-b400-f9f8aa743572\"}"

*Get Collection*

But when I call [get collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-a-collection) I get a valid response:

```
var verb = 'GET';
var type = 'colls';
var link = 'dbs/00001/colls/00001';
```

Response:

> "{\"id\":\"00001\",\"indexingPolicy\":{\"indexingMode\":\"consistent\",\"automatic\":true,\"includedPaths\":[{\"path\":\"\/*\",\"indexes\":[{\"kind\":\"Range\",\"dataType\":\"Number\",\"precision\":-1},{\"kind\":\"Range\",\"dataType\":\"String\",\"precision\":-1},{\"kind\":\"Spatial\",\"dataType\":\"Point\"}]}],\"excludedPaths\":[]},\"_rid\":\"0eUiAJMAdQA=\",\"_ts\":1454200014,\"_self\":\"dbs\/0eUiAA==\/colls\/0eUiAJMAdQA=\/\",\"_etag\":\"\\"00000100-0000-0000-0000-56ad54ce0000\\"\",\"_docs\":\"docs\/\",\"_sprocs\":\"sprocs\/\",\"_triggers\":\"triggers\/\",\"_udfs\":\"udfs\/\",\"_conflicts\":\"conflicts\/\"}"

*List Documents*

Requesting [list documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/list-documents) on that collection gives me this error:

```
var verb = 'GET';
var type = 'docs';
var link = 'dbs/00001/colls/00001/docs';
```

Response:

> "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\ndocs\ndbs/00001/colls/00001\nsat, 12 aug 2017 12:34:48 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 57097e95-c41b-4770-b91a-370418ef2cce\"}"

*Get Document*

Not surprisingly, fetching a [single document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-a-document) works fine:

```
var verb = 'GET';
var type = 'docs';
var link = 'dbs/00001/colls/00001/docs/e7fe638d-2152-2097-f9c6-9801d7cf5cdd';
```

Response:

> "{\"name\":\"test rest api\",\"id\":\"e7fe638d-2152-2097-f9c6-9801d7cf5cdd\",\"_rid\":\"0eUiAJMAdQCbHgAAAAAAAA==\",\"_self\":\"dbs\/0eUiAA==\/colls\/0eUiAJMAdQA=\/docs\/0eUiAJMAdQCbHgAAAAAAAA==\/\",\"_etag\":\"\\"0d00d1ee-0000-0000-0000-598ef7d40000\\"\",\"_attachments\":\"attachments\/\",\"_ts\":1502541779}"

*Query Documents*

Finally, sending a [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/query-documents) also results in a token error:

```
var verb = 'POST';
var type = 'docs';
var link = 'dbs/00001/colls/00001/docs';
var body = `{"query":"SELECT * FROM c", "parameters": []}`;
```

Response:

> "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\ndocs\ndbs/00001/colls/00001\nsat, 12 aug 2017 12:35:42 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: b8b95f8c-1339-423e-b0e7-0d15d3056180\"}"

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems server is not including resource link in calculating signature (`get\ndbs\n\nsat...` ... shouldn't server be using something like `get\ndbs\n/dbs\nsat...`)?

Comment: You're right, I'm looking into that now.  Thank you.

Comment: Please try by removing the `/` in the beginning of request links from the requests that are failing. So the resource link should be `dbs` and `dbs/00001/colls` in your example.

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work for dbs, colls, docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the documentation is incorrect. Where they say `resourceLink`, they should actually say `resource id`. If you look at the Node SDK code, this is how they are calculating the authorization header (notice the use of `resourceId`):

```
getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey: function (verb, resourceId, resourceType, headers, masterKey) {
    var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");

    var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +
               (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +
               (resourceId || "") + "\n" +
               (headers["x-ms-date"] || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +
               (headers["date"] || "").toLowerCase() + "\n";

    var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");

    var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");

    var MasterToken = "master";

    var TokenVersion = "1.0";

    return "type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature;
},
```

So if you want to list the databases, because there is no resource id you will need to use an empty string for your `link` variable. Similarly, if you want to list collections in the database, the link should actually be the id of the database (e.g. `dbs/00001` and not `dbs/00001/colls`).

Comment: @Fergus What do you mean?

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior but your suggestion doesn't seem to help. What is the difference between "Resource ID", "Resource Type", and "Resource Link"? This might be my confusion.

Comment: @Progger May I suggest you post another question with all the details?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue. For querying documents I was getting authorization token error. It was due to wrong ResourceId/ResourceLink

```
var verb = 'POST';
var type = 'docs';
var link = 'dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs';
var url = `${uri}/${link}`;
var resourceLink = "dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}"

getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, type, resourceLink, headers['x-ms-date'], key)
```

the only correction is required from the given question data is to change the appropriate resourceLink while generating AuthorizationToken. For querying Documents the resourceLink is <dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}> instead of <dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs>

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide another thing to consider in addressing this issue. In my case I had to add this header: **x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition: true**, because I created my container with a partitionKey.

I also want to confirm how my main parameters were setup to calculate the authorization header for querying over Documents:

```
resourceType: docs
resourceLink: dbs/<databaseId>/colls/<containerId>
```

I had thought, up to this point, that the resourceLInk had to match with the request URL but this is showing me I was wrong. Similarly notice that the resourceType is not present in the resourceLink.

```
POST /dbs/<databaseId>/colls/<containerId>/docs HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json
x-ms-documentdb-isquery: true
x-ms-version: 2018-12-31
authorization: type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%***********************
x-ms-date: Sat, 03 Apr 2021 22:34:24 GMT
x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition: true
x-correlation-id: be1b1fe1-94cc-11eb-a0a4-38f9d3924940
Host: <host>.documents.azure.com
User-Agent: AHC/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/query+json
Content-Length: 72

{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM <containerId>",
  "parameters": [
    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while making an update to document DB but in my case I realized I was using the Read-Only keys. After changing connection string to use it to Read-Write Keys, I was able to update the records.