# What is the correct Authorization header for querying a Cosmos DB?

Tags: postman, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query my cosmos db for documents and I am having trouble generating the correct authorization header, the example in the official documentation does not show querying.

I am trying it in Postman using Javascript by POST to this URI:

```
POST https://MyDatabase.documents.azure.com:443/dbs/MyContainer/colls/MyDocuments/docs
```

With these headers:

[image]

The authorization is generated like this:

```
var now = new Date().toUTCString(); 
pm.request.headers.upsert({key: "x-ms-date", value: now })

var verb = 'POST'; 
var resourceType = "docs"; 
var resourceLink = 'dbs/MyContainer/colls/MyCollection/docs'; 
var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
           (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
           (resourceLink || "") + "\n" + 
           now.toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
           "" + "\n"; 


//Hash and Encode by using the masterkey.
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("MyMasterKey"); 
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 
var authToken = encodeURIComponent("type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + signature);
pm.request.headers.upsert({key: "Authorization", value: authToken })
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\ndocs\ndbs/MyContainer/colls/MyCollection\nwed, 27 may 2020 19:34:41 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 724657c7-0532-4c5d-a7ff-c95900ef13cf, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"
}
```

I am guessing my signature is created wrong, what is the correct format?

Comment: I provided an answer to to solve this scenario in this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645389/documentdb-rest-api-authorization-token-error/66936541#66936541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our docs on our [Authorization Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources) should have what you're looking for.

hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A required fix for your scenario is that you have to remove "/docs" at the end of the resourceLink value -keep it in the request URL- and also if your containter was created using a partitionKey you have to add the following header:

```
'x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition': true
```